# Ubuntu 18.04 and it's spins freeze on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, system

I tried Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu - all 18.04. With Xubuntu 16.04 I had it too. They hang on shutdown - load sign rotates without stopping or hangs too. I always have to shut it down by pressing power button.

Here is [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1acPBs8-9T97yBbyFGVKnc97Ol53h1cc6).

Answer (score 2):

Suspend doesn't work in 18.04 either for me and many others. Reboot works though. If reboot works for you too then from Grub menu it is safer to power off.

In the GRUB menu, press `C` and then enter `halt`

Hopefully 18.04 will be mostly fixed by the July 26, 2018 release of version `18.04.1`.

Comment: @RS I'm running regular Ubuntu and cannot duplicate your results. Lets wait a few days and see if the freeze comes back. If not that's great.

Comment: with regular Ubuntu it happens too for me: hangs on 2nd dot.

Comment: it freezes on halt.

Comment: I am experiencing same issue. It was same with the 16.04 version, though I though is due the way I installed as I am using back Ubuntu Desktop after 8 years. Then if is a bug hopefully will got solved

Comment: @CarmineTambascia When 16.04 first came out I had some suspend/resume stumbling blocks but got them all worked out after a couple of weeks. The same might be true for 18.04 but I only boot into it for bug testing. Periodically I clone my 16.04 to the 18.04 partition and run the upgrade process on it to see what's changed.

Comment: @RS It is supposed to "freeze" on "halt". It means it's powered down.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix unfortunately I moved to teh 18.04 from teh 16, because few weeks ago, it crashed. after 2 months that was working, without reason. Was the 3rd time. The first and second I though was due the way I did the partition(is a laptop legion Y520 that got both a hdd and an ssd). This is the reason for the installation for the 18, I left do the partition automatically. So ar seems good, as previously at every boot was cleaning some file in some folder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's related to your issue and I haven't tested suspend yet, but I found a better workaround to shutdown.  If I restart the laptop, I can power off from the GDM login screen so it goes like this:

Push power button to start laptop;
Log in and do your thing;
Restart;
Power off from GDM;

No idea why it works. I absolutely have to restart once before I can power off.  My issue is related to nVidia drivers and Prime.  I didn't have this issue on 16.04 using the 384 driver.

Comment: Would you mind to confirm affection: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771708

Comment: I was using the 384 driver and thought I'd install the 390 driver to make things better. It just made things break and I went back to `prime-select intel` instead.